# How to make various subsets of data in a few lines in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a way to create various subsets of data without having to use the subset function for each subset.

Say I have a df that looks like this:

```
    female_ID   dispersal_distance  distance_bin
           A1                  230  500 m and below
           B1                  629  500 m - 1000 m
           C1                  888  500 m - 1000 m
           D1                 1236  1000 m - 1500 m
           E1                 1777  1500 m - 2000 m
           F1                 2314  2000 m - 2500 m
           G1                 2762  2500 m - 3000 m
```

Right now a lot of my code consists of code that looks like this:

```
    df1 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '500 m and below')
    df2 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '500 m - 1000 m')
    df3 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '1000 m - 1500 m')
    df4 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '1500 m - 2000 m')        
    df5 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '2000 m - 2500 m')        
    df6 <- subset(df, distance_bin == '2500 m - 3000 m')
```

Is there a way to do what I did above in one line?

Thanks

EDIT:

With the suggestion of  @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 and @Rui Barradas, I have this:

```
     df_list <- split(df, df$distance_bin)
     names(df_list) <- paste0("df", seq_along(df_list))
     list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

And it gives me the separate df1, df2, df3, etc. data frames. Although it isn't one line of code, this is still helpful and it reduces the amount of lines of code, so thanks!!

Comment: You can `split` the data and keep it in a `list`. If you really need the separate `data.frames`, you can then use `list2env`....

Comment: After the `split` suggested by  @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, you can do `names(df_list) <- paste0("df", seq_along(df_list))`.

Comment: This is more of a methodological, open-ended remark: whatever you're trying to do, you probably don't really need to (or should) split such a data frame into six smaller data frames.

Comment: Use split: `split(df, df$distance_bin)` and if you need to further run processing on each subset use by: `by(df, df$distance_bin, FUN=function(df) ...)`. Both will return a named list of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Three-liner

```
dd <- read.table(text = "female_ID   dispersal_distance  distance_bin
                            A1                  230  500_m_and_below
                            B1                  629  500_m_-_1000_m
                            C1                  888  500_m_-_1000_m
                            D1                 1236  1000_m_-_1500_m
                            E1                 1777  1500_m_-_2000_m
                            F1                 2314  2000_m_-_2500_m
                            G1                 2762  2500_m_-_3000_m", header = T,stringsAsFactor = F)



Fsplit <- function(x,y){ 
  ls <- split(x,y) 
  list2env(ls,envir = .GlobalEnv) 
} 

Fsplit(dd,dd$distance_bin)
```

A new dataframe is created in your environment based on the group name

Comment: thanks for your input DataTx! It wasn't me who down voted, but I'm assuming maybe they down voted because I wanted to also create separate data frames. I do end up using the split function, but that gives me a list of the separate data frames. I have to do a couple other things in order to get the actual separate data frames.